# Cherrypy handling requests differently

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am trying to figure out a way where I need to have two different pages calling one function and the function will handle the requests accordingly based on which function called.

The flow can be either the `predict function` handles based on the calling function or that it will return a value to the calling function and then the calling function page reloads to show the result as it has to be shown.

```
Class GSpam:

    @cherrypy.expose
    def main(self,contents=""):
        return call predict

    @cherrypy.expose
    def alt(self):
        return """<html>
        <div align=center>
          <body>
        <br>
        <br>
            <form method="post" action="predict">
              <input type="text" value="Enter post to check" name="text" />
              <button type="submit">Predict!</button>
            </form>
        </div>
          </body>
        </html>"""

    @cherrpy.expose
    def predict(self,text):
        do some stuff
        check which function called and return accordingly
        return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = 80
    api = cherrypy.dispatch.RoutesDispatcher()
    api.connect('home','/',controller=GSpam,action='main')
    conf = {'/': {'request.dispatch': api}}
    cherrypy.config.update({
        'server.socket_host' : "0.0.0.0",
        'server.socket_port' : int(port),
        'server.thread_pool' : 10,
        'engine.autoreload.on' : False,
        'response.timeout' : 10
    })
    app=cherrypy.tree.mount(root=None,config=conf)
```

I haven't used cherrypy before. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a private method:

```
class GSpam:

   def _predict(self, text, from_='original'):
       if from_ == 'original':
          return "Something very different"
       else:
          return "Content for %s" % from_

   @cherrypy.expose
   def main(self,contents=""):
       return self._predict(contents, 'main')

   @cherrypy.expose
   def alt(self):
       return """<html>
       <div align=center>
         <body>
       <br>
       <br>
           <form method="post" action="predict">
            <input type="text" value="Enter post to check" name="text" />
            <button type="submit">Predict!</button>
           </form>
       </div>
         </body>
       </html>"""

   @cherrypy.expose
   def predict(self, text):
       #do some stuff
       result = self._predict(text)
       return result
```

Comment: You mean adding an additional parameter in another private function which decides where the call is coming from . Would keep that in mind for later. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I had tried something which works for me. I had used the form action on the function itself . This doesn't exactly handle based on which function calls the other function as mentioned in the question but the same function which calls the other function handles itself by using form action on itself.

```
    @cherrypy.expose
        def index(self,text=""):

            cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml'
            try:
                if not text:
                    cherrypy.response.status = 400
                    return "<error>\n<code>400</code>\n<msg>empty text</msg>\n</error>"
                else:

                    res=self.predict(text)
                    res=[map(lambda x : "spam" if x==0 else "ham" ,res[0]),res[1]]
                    return '<?xml version="1.0"?><Result>\n<Logistic_Regression>\n<Label>'+res[0][1]+'</Label>\n<Score>'+str(res[1][1])+'</Score>\n</Logistic_Regression>\n<Linear_SVM>\n<Label>'+res[0][0]+'</Label>\n<Score>'+str(res[1][0])+'</Score>\n</Linear_SVM>\n<Random_Forest>\n<Label>'+res[0][2]+'</Label>\n<Score>'+str(res[1][2])+'</Score>\n</Random_Forest>\n</Result>' 

            except Exception, e:
                cherrypy.response.status = 500
                return "<error>\n<code>500</code>\n<msg>%s</msg>\n</error>" % traceback.format_exc()


        @cherrypy.expose
        def alt(self,text="",is_money=""):
            if text=="":
                return """<html>
                <div align=center>
                <h1>Spam Detector</h1>
                <title>Spam Detector</title>
                <body>
                <br>
                <form method="post" action="alt">
                <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter post to check" name="text" />
                <br><br>
                Is Money : <input type="radio" name="is_money" value="y" checked> Y<input type="radio" name="is_money" value="n">N
                &emsp;<button type="submit">Predict!</button>
                </form>
                </div>
                </body>
            </html>"""
            else:
                res=self.predict(text,is_money)
                res=[map(lambda x : "<font color='red'>spam" if x==0 else "<font color='green'>ham" ,res[0]),res[1]]
                print res
                text= text + "<br> #money" if is_money=="y" else text
                separator="<br><br><div align=center><hr width=50%></div><br><br>"
                htmlstart="""<html>
                <div align=center>
                <h1>Spam Detector</h1>
                <title>Spam Detector</title>
                <body>
                <br>
                <br>
                <form method="post" action="alt">
                <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter post to check" name="text" />
                <br>
                Is Money : <input type="radio" name="is_money" value="y" checked> Y<input type="radio" name="is_money" value="n">N
                <button type="submit">Predict!</button>
                </form>
                </div><div align=center>"""+separator
                htmlend="</body></html>"
                html="<b><table border=0 style='width:60%' cellspacing=20  ><tr><td align='center' valign='middle'><font color = 'navy'><b>Logistic Regression</td><td></td><td align='center' valign='middle'><b><font color='navy'>Linear SVM</b></font></td><td></td><td align='center' valign='middle'><b><font color='navy'>Random Forest</b></font></td></tr><tr><td align='center' valign='middle'><h1>"+res[0][1]+"</font></h1></td><td></td><td align='center' valign='middle'><h1>"+res[0][0]+"</font></h1></td><td></td><td align='center' valign='middle'><h1>"+res[0][2]+"</font></h1></td></tr><tr><td align='center' valign='middle' colspan=5><font color='orangered'><b>Text : <font color='orange'>"+text+"</td></tr><tr><td align='center' valign='middle'><font color='navy'><b>Probability : <font color='blue'>"+str(res[1][1])+"</b></td><td></td><td align='center' valign='middle'><b><font color='navy'>Probability : <font color='blue'>"+str(res[1][0])+"</font></b></td><td></td><td align='center' valign='middle'><font color='navy'><b>Probability : <font color='blue'>"+str(res[1][2])+"</b></td></tr></table>"
                if 'html' not in cherrypy.session:
                    cherrypy.session['html']=[html]
                else:
                    li=cherrypy.session['html']
                    li.append(html)
                    cherrypy.session['html']=li[-5:]
                txt=separator.join((cherrypy.session['html'])[::-1])
                return htmlstart+txt+htmlend
def predict(self,text="",is_money=""):
     return do_Something
```